# React Select onClick redirect page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, gatsby, react-select

I am very new react.js. I am using react-select as a drop down with a button for the onClick action. I am having trouble getting the URL to update dynamically. For example the users chooses Netflix in the drop down menu and clicks the select button it will re-direct them to Netflix URL. How can i dynamically update the URL link using react-select with a button.

````
import Select, { components } from 'react-select';
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import homePageStyles from './home-page.module.scss'

const type = [
    { value: 'netflix', label: 'netflix' },
    { value: 'amazon', label: 'amazon' },
    { value: 'facebook', label: 'facebook'}
]
const searchButton = `${homePageStyles.button} ${homePageStyles.search}`

const Choose = (props) => (
<div>
    {<div>CHOOSE</div>}
    <components.Control {...props} />
</div>
); 

export default class SearchStraws extends Component {
  state = {}
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={homePageStyles.product}>
        <div className="call-product-container">
          <div className={homePageStyles.callOut}>
          <Select
            isClearable
            components={{ Control: Choose }}
            isSearchable
            options={type}
          />
          </div>
          <div className={homePageStyles.callOut}>
                <button className={searchButton}>
                  <Link to="www.netflix.com">Search</Link>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Links are for internal urls, you should be using the html a tags like so

```
          <a
            href={`https://www.netflix.com/`}
            target={'_blank'}
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Netflix
          </a>
```

Comment: probably something like https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html will help you